# Publishesettings tells that location is reserved system name or disk not writeable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure

I'm trying to get started with Windows Azure with C# Mvc yada yada, the works :D

I've got a 90 day trail and got to the part where I have downloaded the xxx.publishsettings file, but when I try to import it MS Web Dev 2010 Express tells me:

"The location specified cannot be created. Check that the location is not reserved system name, and that the disk i writeable and that there is enough room on the disk."

Im running Web Dev as Admin if that counts for something?

Comment: Does it list the express version as supported?

Comment: I guess so? I've just downloaded the installer and since I dont have Visual Studio on this computer it installed Web Dev Express by itself with the Azure stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could have a virus that is causing it to restrict access to certain thing i have had the same problem before just put your computer into safe mode and roll it back then try again if it doesn't work try just doing it in safe mode